# Serializing objects in Java that are part of an inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: java

I've got some classes in an inheritance hierarchy, with state that needs to be serialized. Something like:

```
public class Base {
    private int b;

    public void serialize(Writer w) {
        w.write(b);
    }
}

public class DerivedA extends Base {
   private int a;

   public void serialize(Writer w) {
      super.serialize(w);
      w.write(a, some_option);
}

public class DerivedC extends Base {
   private int c;

   public void serialize(Writer w) {
       super.serialize(w);
       w.write(c, some_other_option);
   }
}
```

Expand this to a couple dozen classes and a couple dozen members per class, and it's a bit of a maintenance problem. I'd like to encode this logic by changing the members to property objects, then using reflection or something to find the fields to serialize.

I can't figure out a good way to get all of a class' inherited fields though, especially with inheritance chains deeper than the toy example. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Usually, when you feel like reflection is the answer (especially non-trivial reflection which is what would be required here), it points to a design problem that needs to be improved in code. That's almost certainly the case here - but it's very difficult to say exactly how you should change it without seeing the wider context of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, calling this "static behavior" is a bit misleading.  That implies you are talking about `static` methods.  But you aren't, and (technically) Java `static` methods and fields are not inherited / inheritable anyway.

The nub of your question is this:

> I can't figure out a good way to get all of a class' inherited fields [using reflection], especially with inheritance chains deeper than the toy example. What's the best way to do this?

The way to do it is to visit all classes in the target classes chain of superclasses, calling `Class::getDeclaredFields()` to get all fields declared by the class.  (This doesn't include inherited fields ... hence the need to *traverse* the chain.)  For each field returned, you need to figure out what you are going to do in your serializer, based on the type and modifiers.  For a private field, you will need to use `Field::setAccessible`.  This is expensive, so a *typical* serializer implementation captures the information that it needs and cache it.

This may not seem like a "good" way, but AFAIK it is the *only* way ... assuming that you are implementing your own serialization framework.  The alternative is to use a pre-existing serialization framework; e.g. Object streams, JAXB, Jackson, GSON, etcetera.  Or a JPA or JDP based data persistence mechanism.

Comment: You're right, the crux of my question is how to serialize this state without repeating myself all over the place. I don't think plain old java serialization will work for me here because some of the fields are references to other complex objects, for which I might want to e.g. just serialize an ID. Would it be appropriate to ask another question for recommending a framework, or is that off topic?

Comment: It is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what your classes represent, it sounds like to be a job for composition and not inheritance. Wrap them inside other classes.

You could try `int b` in one class and `int a` in another and so on and make another class that hold those in fields. [Google Immutables](https://immutables.github.io), a library that generates immutable and serializable classes by annotation processing, was made exactly for these sort of things.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java's good old (available since JDK 1.1) `Serializable` and `ObjectOutputStream` functionality, which internally relies on reflection but you don't need to worry about that:

```
public class Base implements Serializable {
    private int b;

    public void serialize(Writer w) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(this);            
        w.write(new String(baos.toByteArray());
    }
}

public class DerivedA extends Base {
   private int a;    
}

public class DerivedC extends Base {
   private int c;
}
```

Although this still works, it's outdated, and nowadays I would generally recommend using Jackson to serialize into JSON format instead of the binary format that comes out of `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on Stephen C's answer, there's more nuance to how things need to be serialized than Serializable accounts for. Thanks for the answer though.